TYPO3 v12 form method="get" only redirects to default action
I need to create a TYPO3 form, that passes values via get parameters to an controller action.
The form looks like this:
<f:form action="filter" name="filter-form" method="get" class="filter-form">

The plugin has two actions: list, filter. The form should redirect to the filter action. As soon as I change the method to post it works. But with the method get it doesnt.
When looking in the rendered markup, it seems to be correct:
<form method="get" name="filter-form" class="filter-form" action="/page/?tx_extension_plugin%5Baction%5D=filter&tx_extension_plugin%5Bcontroller%5D=Filter&cHash=7b6cbdc9134c8a5ea040c88c20552607">


Does anyone have an idea?
I also tried using the actionUri instead of action. Or defining the action with {f:action.uri(...)}.
EDIT:
In the forms hidden fields, the action is defined to be list somehow.
<input type="hidden" name="tx_extension_plugin[__referrer][@action]" value="list">


Do you get any type of error? "It doesnt work" isn't a real good description of what's happening when sending the form. Check the Network-Tab in the developer tools at least to check the http result.

@Mogens I don't get errors. The default action 'list' is called and executed. So it runs without throwing any errors. I tried to work around it and handle the request with the list action. That works, but isn't a good solution.
To me it seems that the problem is in generating the request, not in handling it.

Is filter a cachable action? The action-attribute is filled with an URI including  `cHash. By adding additional parameters (which might be the case for a filter, I guess), the cHash evaluation will fail...

@JulianHofmann the filter action is defined as non cachable. But you could be right about the cHash. I haven't had any contact with that subject yet and would have to dive deeper into it. What I have read so far, however, is that the get parameters are passed without being defined as excludedParameters.
I don't know if that is also neccessary on a non chachable action and if that changes the called action

controller="string" ? -> https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Form.html

Thanks for your answer. Tried it. Doesn't change the outcome

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
